# Want to choose characters before Game Starts

Tags: javascript, jquery, constructor

I have some questions about choosing the characters before game starts. Now you can check the demo with this [Link](https://sangumee.github.io/Udacity-Classic-Arcade-Game/) and also repo with this [Link](https://github.com/sangumee/Udacity-Classic-Arcade-Game)

I use VEX Library to use dialog but I heard in jQuery I can use native dialog but in version3.3.1 they are not working so I use VEX Library now.

First, I want to make it choose the character that I want.
When I access my project I can see like this page.

[image]

and each buttons have value so when I click the buttons they log the each characters. You can check the code.

```
// To choose Character with VEX Library
function CharacterChoose() {
    vex.dialog.open({
        message: 'Which character do you want to play?',
        input: [
            '<label for="char-boy"><img src="images/char-boy.png" class="imagepadding" /></label>',
            '<img src="images/char-cat-girl.png" class="imagepadding" />',
            '<img src="images/char-pink-girl.png" class="imagepadding" />',
            '<img src="images/char-horn-girl.png" class="imagepadding" />',
            '<img src="images/char-princess-girl.png" class="imagepadding" />'
        ].join(''),
        buttons: [
            $.extend({}, vex.dialog.buttons.NO, {
                text: 'Char-Princess-Girl',
                click: function () {
                    this.value = 'char-princess-girl';
                    this.close();
                }
            }),
            $.extend({}, vex.dialog.buttons.NO, {
                text: 'Char-Horn-Girl',
                click: function () {
                    this.value = 'char-horn-girl';
                    this.close();
                }
            }),
            $.extend({}, vex.dialog.buttons.NO, {
                text: 'Char-Pink-Girl',
                click: function () {
                    this.value = 'char-pink-girl';
                    this.close();
                }
            }),
            $.extend({}, vex.dialog.buttons.NO, {
                text: 'Char-Cat-Girl',
                click: function () {
                    this.value = 'char-cat-girl';
                    this.close();
                }
            }),
            $.extend({}, vex.dialog.buttons.NO, {
                text: 'Char-Boy',
                click: function () {
                    this.value = 'char-boy';
                    this.close();
                }
            })
        ],
        callback: function (value) {
            // char-boy','char-cat-girl','char-horn-girl','char-pink-girl','char-princess-girl
            switch (value) {
                case "char-boy":
                    console.log('You choose Char-boy');
                    break;
                case "char-cat-girl":
                    console.log('You choose Char-Cat-Girl');
                    break;
                case "char-horn-girl":
                    console.log('you choose Char-Horn-Girl');
                    break;
                case "char-pink-girl":
                    console.log('You Choose Char-Pink-Girl');
                    break;
                case "char-princess-girl":
                    console.log('You Choose Char-Princess-Girl');
                    break;
                default:
                case "char-boy":
                    console.log('You choose Char-boy');
                    break;
            }
        }
    })
}
```

so the value is important but actually I don't know how can I get that value into Player variable.

```
let Player = function (x, y, speed, value) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.sprite = 'images/' + value + '.png';

};
```

I write code like this because when I start the project and select the character and I want get a value to there so this.sprite can read the right URL. But I don't know How can I think about the logic and get the value from there.

Comment: maybe you can do call this inside your switch part `Player.sprite = 'images/' + value + '.png';`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Thanks! I got an idea. I solved the problem!!!